# Get Id and Type from Html.DropDownList to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, drop-down-menu

I have a class called

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

My MVC View Page is Strongly typed to Person and there is a dropdownlist which show the list of countries.

In My Controller Index

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    LoadCountryList();
    return View(Person);
}

private void LoadCountryList()
{
    IEnumerable<CountryList> countryList = CountryListService.GetCountryList();
    ViewData["CountryList"] = new SelectList(country, "Id", "Type", 0);
}
```

Code in the html

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country.Id, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["CountryList"], "--Select--")%>
```

When the page is submitted Create method is called in the controller

```
public ActionResult Create(Person person)
{
    // person.Country.Id has the value
    // person.Country.Type is null
}
```

I am getting only the Country Id from the object person in the Create Method. The Country Id is loaded inside the Person Object under Country.

Is there any way I can get both the Id and Type of the country when passed from the Page to the Controller?

I know I am passing Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country.Id .... from here.

Is there any Solution so that I get Id and Type in the controller.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409394/html-dropdownlist-mvc3-confusion/8336039#8336039

Answer (score 0):

Passing it through the person object is not the best way to do it.  Instead, assign an ID to your dropdown list like this:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(
      model => model.Country.Id, 
      (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["CountryList"], "--Select--")
      new { id = "CountryID" }
%>
```

and then put that in as a parameter to your Create method:

```
public ActionResult Create(Person person, int CountryID)
{
   var country = CountryListService.GetCountryList().Where(x => x.id == CountryID);

   person.Country = country;
   ...
}
```

ASP .NET MVC will look for a control that has the same ID name as the parameter in the method call and pass it through.